# Error when retargeting Animation to Human mesh

Tags: python, animation, mesh, objects, armature

I'm using Rokoko plugin. Does anyone have a solution to this error?

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91904\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-master\operators\retargeting.py", line 219, in execute
    self.bake_animation(armature_source, armature_target, root_bones)
  File "C:\Users\91904\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-master\operators\retargeting.py", line 527, in bake_animation
    bpy.data.actions.remove(action)
ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Action has been removed
```

*****************************Or sometime this error****************************************

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91904\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-master\operators\retargeting.py", line 219, in execute
    self.bake_animation(armature_source, armature_target, root_bones)
  File "C:\Users\91904\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.4\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-master\operators\retargeting.py", line 454, in bake_animation
    armature_target.animation_data.action.name = 'RSL_RETARGETING_' + str(frame)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'action'
```

Comment: The question is less suitable for this platform, since the focus here is on the use of Blender. The problem is probably related to a bug in the plugin. You should actually contact Rokoko with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. You need to make sure the target armature has an action assigned to it.

1. Select your target armature (the one you want to add animation to).
2. In the action editor click 'New'.
3. Hit retarget in Rokoko addon and it should work now.

I still get the first error message when retargeting in Blender 3.4 but it does work as long as the target has an action assigned before you retarget.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I still get this error "ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Action has been removed". Hopefully, someone will solve this in blender 3.4. But Roko Addon working smoothly in blender 3.2 without any errors.

Sometimes the model hand looks weird after retargeting, I understand why it is happening. Choose this from the rebuilding bone list:
rCollar- RightShouder
rShldr- RightArm
lCollar- LeftShoulder
lShldr- LeftArm